# Veeam Agent on Ubuntu Having Issues Creating Snapshot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup

I have a server running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and I have installed Veeam Agent on it. I have it set to backup to another server on my LAN running Veeam Backup And Replication. I have another server running CentOS 8 that can backup that it just fine & the issue only seems to be on my Ubuntu server.

```
   22:26:53         Job macmini-backup started at 2021-06-04 02:26:53 UTC
  22:27:04         Preparing to backup
  22:27:07         Waiting for backup infrastructure resources availability                         00:00:02
  22:27:09         [error] Failed to create volume snapshot                                         00:00:04
  22:27:13         [error] Failed to take volume snapshot
  22:27:13         [error] Failed to perform backup
  22:27:13         [error] Invalid argument
  22:27:13         [error] Failed to execute IOCTL_TRACKING_ADD
  22:27:13         [error] Processing finished with errors at 2021-06-04 02:27:13 UTC
```

I have also been into the log file but it doesn't seem to give more information other than what I have here. I already installed the generic Linux headers as well. File system is ext4.

Comment: Try submitting an Issue with Veeam - it's on best effort basis if you're not paying them, but maybe it helps: https://www.veeam.com/kb1771

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS uses Kernel 5.8, which doesn't support Veeams Snapshot mechanism any more. See

https://forums.veeam.com/veeam-agents-for-linux-mac-aix-solaris-f41/fedora-33-kernel-5-8-t70158.html

for details.

https://helpcenter.veeam.com/docs/agentforlinux/userguide/system_requirements.html?ver=50#considerations-and-limitations says:

> For Ubuntu 20.04 and 20.10 with Linux kernel version 5.8 or later, consider the following limitations:
>
> - The veeam-nosnap_5.0.0.4318_amd64.deb package is required.
> - Snapshot-less file-level backup is supported only.